# file handling plus tokenization in c

Tags: c, file, token, tokenize

What I am trying to do is to take input of following format from standard input

Input:

```
22|Subject 1|45
23|Subject 2|52
22|Subject 2|51
26|Subject 1|72
23|Subject 2|61
26|Subject 1|81
```

which is nothing but
STUDENT ID|SUBJECT|MARKS
Now I want to tokenize these details and store them in structure variables so that I could do calculations on them. This code is not working. The printf in the last line is giving 5 0 as output, which is not correct. Please help.

```c
struct student
{
  int sid;
  char sub[35];
  int marks;
};


void main()
{
  struct student std[16];
  int i,ch,j;
  char temp[50];
  FILE *fp;
  clrscr();
  //fp=fopen("xyz.txt", "r");
  //fscanf(fp,"%s", temp);
  //printf("\n%s", temp);
  i=0;
  std[i].sid=0;
  while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && i < 6)
  {
    std[i].sid = 10 * std[i].sid + (int)(ch - '0');
    while((ch = getchar()) != '|')
    {
      std[i].sid = 10 * std[i].sid + (int)(ch - '0');
    }
    while((ch = getchar()) != '|')
    {
      std[i].sub[j++] = ch;
    }
    std[i].sub[j] = '\0';
    std[i].marks = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
      std[i].sid = 10 * std[i].marks + (int)(ch - '0');
    }
    i++;

    if (i < 6)
      std[i].sid = 0;
  }
  printf("%d %s %d",std[0].sid, &(std[1].sub[0]), std[2].marks);
  //fclose(fp);
  getch();
}
```

Comment: It's `int main()` not `void main()`.

Comment: i am using an old compiler which supports void main also. by the way, problem remains same even if i make it int and return 0 in the end

Comment: Yes, that has nothing to do with the problem, are you allowed to use the `string.h` header? And `&std[1].sub[0]` -> `std[1].sub`, is the same thing. Why the last line has different indices for the struct array subscript?

Comment: @iharob yes i am allowed to use strtok(), but i am unable to use that, and also i am having trouble in the approach that i have used... i have already tried std[1].sub, but since that didn't work, i kept on changing the code, even i tried to apply the same approach on a file using getc in place of gatchar ( you can see FILE hanling statements in comments). That is also givning the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine with a couple of fixes.

- Reset `j` to `0` after populating subject
- You used `std[i].sid` instead of `std[i].marks` when computing the mark

To print out all the data at the end:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    printf("%d %s %d\n", std[i].sid, &(std[i].sub[0]), std[i].marks);
```

The complete code (I added a shim for `clrscr()` as I don't have `conio.h`):

```
// parser.c - Parses student data into struct
// To compile:
//  gcc parser.c -o parser
// To run:
//  ./parser < data.txt

#include <stdio.h> // So compiler doesn't complain

// Shim for clrscr() if <conio.h> not available
void clrscr()
{
    printf("\e[2J\e[1;1H");
}

struct student
{
  int sid;
  char sub[35];
  int marks;
};


void main()
{
  struct student std[16];
  int i,ch,j;
  char temp[50];
  FILE *fp;
  clrscr();
  //fp=fopen("xyz.txt", "r");
  //fscanf(fp,"%s", temp);
  //printf("\n%s", temp);
  i=0;
  std[i].sid=0;
  while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && i < 6)
  {
    std[i].sid = 10 * std[i].sid + (int)(ch - '0');
    while((ch = getchar()) != '|')
    {
      std[i].sid = 10 * std[i].sid + (int)(ch - '0');
    }
    while((ch = getchar()) != '|')
    {
      std[i].sub[j++] = ch;
    }
    std[i].sub[j] = '\0';
    std[i].marks = 0;
    j = 0; // Reset j to 0

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
      std[i].marks = 10 * std[i].marks + (int)(ch - '0');
    }
    i++;

    if (i < 6)
      std[i].sid = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    printf("%d %s %d\n", std[i].sid, &(std[i].sub[0]), std[i].marks);
  //fclose(fp);
  //getch(); // Commented out as not needed/don't have <conio.h>
}
```

The output using your data:

```
22 Subject 1 45
23 Subject 2 52
22 Subject 2 51
26 Subject 1 72
23 Subject 2 61
26 Subject 1 81
```

It compiled fine under Linux using `gcc` with the additions at the top of the code listing.

Comment: are you sure? you made only two changes?

Comment: I just added `j = 0;` and fixed the `std[i].marks` bit (the second while loop was assigning the marks to `sid` and not `marks`).

The only other changes were commenting out `getch()` as I don't have `conio.h`, adding `#include <stdio.h>`, and adding a shim for `clrscr()` (could just be commented out). To be sure just do a `diff` on you code and the code I posted.

Comment: I also added a `for` loop at the end to print out all the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the library functions instead of doing it all by hand, just like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
  int sid;
  char sub[35];
  int marks;
};


int main(void)
{
  struct student std[16];
  size_t i;
  size_t count;
  char   line[100];

  i          = 0;
  std[i].sid = 0;
  count      = sizeof(std) / sizeof(std[0]);
  while (((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) != NULL) && (i < count))
  {
    char *token;
    char *endptr;

    token = strtok(line, "|");
    if (token == NULL)
      continue;        
    std[i].sid = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);
    if (*endptr != '\0')
      continue;

    token = strtok(NULL, "|");
    if (token == NULL)
      continue;
    /* WARNING: no bound checking is being performed, DANGER ... */
    strcpy(std[i].sub, token);

    token = strtok(NULL, "|");
    if (token == NULL)
      continue;
    std[i].marks = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);
    if (*endptr != '\0')
      continue;

    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. this would definitely help me. but if you tell me whats wrong with my code, i will get to know the correct usage of getchar() and build my concept

Comment: You are using `getchar()` fine, the problem is somewhere in the `printf()` statement itself.

Comment: i am simply trying to print structure contents. printf should only print what that structure is really containing

Comment: Yes. but perhaps `printf("%d %s %d",std[0].sid, std[0].sub, std[0].marks);` is what you really wanted.